# Consultas complejas con sequelize

Tags: javascript, nodejs, orm

Buenas no se muy bien como realizar una consulta compleja con sequelize lo que quiero realmente es pedir
los alumno_health de todos los alumnos que pertenezcan a un centro

```
Centro.findAll({
        include: {
            model: HealthsExtend,
         
            where:{
                idCentro: "centro.idCentro"
            },
            required:true,
            attributes: [[Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('peso')), 'peso'],
            [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('percent_Grasa')),'percent_Grasa'],
            [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('percent_Hidratacion')),'percent_Hidratacion'],
            [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('peso_Muscular')),'peso_Muscular'],
            [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('masa_Muscular')),'masa_Muscular'],
            [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('peso_Oseo')),'peso_Oseo'],
            [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('kilocalorias')),'kilocalorias'],
            [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('edad_Metabolica')),'edad_Metabolica'],
            [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('altura')),'altura'],
            [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('masa_Viseral')),'masa_Viseral'],
            [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('perimetro_Abdominal')),'perimetro_Abdominal'],
            [Sequelize.fn('AVG', Sequelize.col('actividad_Fisica')),'actividad_Fisica'],
        ]
        }
    })
```

Lo que tengo hasta ahora es esto pero en realidad no funcionaria porque HealthExtend(alumno_health) no esta relacionado directamente con el centro
[image: Modelo de datos]